# android bitmap not null but always make nullpointerexception

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, nullpointerexception

i am implementing [topcode](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~mhorn/topcodes/) for android + opencv for android.
topcode is use for get marker position in screen. 
in topcode, scanning method only accept bitmap argument.
so i convert my mat to bitmap.

this is my code

```
private Scanner scanner;
private List<TopCode> codes;
//..........................
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mRgb = inputFrame.rgba();

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgb.cols(), mRgb.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


    try {
            Utils.matToBitmap(mRgb, bmp,true);

            if(bmp != null){


                codes = scanner.scan(bmp); ----> this giving null

            }


        } catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

    }

return mRgb;
}
```

this is error log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.ar.MainActivity.onCameraFrame(MainActivity.java:155)
at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:387)
at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:328)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

i don't know what to do now. please help me.

Comment: which is the 155 line in onCameraFrame method?

Comment: codes = scanner.scan(bmp);

Comment: may be bmp is not null but scanner can be! did you check whether is it null?

Comment: where do you instantiate scanner?

Comment: i don't know how to check scanner.

Comment: if(bmp != null && scanner !=null ) check for error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must initialise your scanner. Your bmp has no problem, you've checked that in your if statement. You can initialise it like this : (just add this line before your try catch statement)

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: you just solved my problem. how stupid i am forgot something basic. hahaha. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code

```
private Scanner scanner;
private List<TopCode> codes;
//..........................
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mRgb = inputFrame.rgba();

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgb.cols(), mRgb.rows(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


    try {
            Utils.matToBitmap(mRgb, bmp,true);

            if(bmp != null){
               if(scanner ==null)
                scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

                codes = scanner.scan(bmp);

            }


        } catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

    }

return mRgb;
}
```